# Atom-photon interaction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-spin, atomic-physics, quantum-electrodynamics

When we describe interaction of atom with EM field, we consider the interaction term in Hamiltonian as follows

$$
W(t) = -\frac{e}{2\mu c} (\hat{A} \hat{p} + \hat{p} \hat{A}) + \frac{e^2}{2\mu c^2} \hat{A} \cdot \hat{A}.
$$

However, this interaction term was derived for interaction of spin $0$ particle with charged particle. Photon has spin $1$, and everything that makes up matter has spin $1/2$! What is going on?

Comment: Things here is: the interaction term is not complete. It omit a lot of terms, including atom absorb photon (energy level of $l\neq0$ involves). Hence, the spin-involved interaction is ``traced out'', and then the interaction with EM field could be well described by this form.